# How to configure consistency level, ttl while using cassandra batch operations in spring-data-cassandra 1.5.1.RELEASE spting-boot 1.5.1.RELEASE

Tags: spring, cassandra, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-data-cassandra

I'm trying to the insert, update, delete operations using the below link. But I would like to configure come options. Please let me know how can I achieve it.

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/tree/1.5.x/spring-data-cassandra/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra

Comment: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-cassandra/blob/1.5.x/spring-data-cassandra/src/test/java/org/springframework/data/cassandra/core/CassandraBatchTemplateIntegrationTests.java
please check the link.

Comment: That's not possible as of Spring Data Cassandra 1.5. Use 2.0.

Comment: @mp911de is there any workaround?